# What do arrays look like?

Tags: arrays, list, pointers, data-structures

I am interested in algorithms and data structures, and have a minor question.

I know that a Generic list contains "cells" that have a pointer to the next cell, and so "insertion" of an element into a list will take a O(1) (constant time).

However, an insertion into array will take a longer time.

Question:
How are normal, static arrays built? is it a number of neighbor regions on a memory? Is it why it's cells don't have pointers to each other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a number of neighbor regions on a memory?

Yes. An array is a contiguous region of memory.

when inserting an element into a specific position, you need to move each element after it down by 1 space. You also have to potentially create a new array and copy all of the elements if there are no more empty spaces.

The tradeoff for this O(N) insertion time is O(1) lookup time. (known as random access). Because you have a pointer to the beginning of the memory, and you know the index of the item you want, it is a trivial calculation to get the memory address.

Answer (score 0):

My friend as we know that array works on contiguous memory allocation scheme so it always maintains the memory at static time and as far as the complexity concern it depends

like

```
 Operation                      Array     Singly Linked List
    Read (any where)            O(1)           O(n)
    Add/Remove at end           O(1)           O(n)
    Add/Remove in the interior  O(n)           O(n)
    Resize                      O(n)           N/A
    Find By position            O(1)           O(n)
    insertion at the beg.       O(n)           O(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats right array is stored in contiguous memory which is static and allocated when the process is initiated, not at run time